# Manifest merger failed issue

Tags: java, android

[image: enter image]

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`

full error code:

```
ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0]
AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).**

Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-19:19 to override.**
```

Comment: so, what's your question ?

Comment: go to the manifest file and select the Merged Manifest option and its show you the conflict and resolve it as per your requirements

Comment: appcompat-v7:28.0.0 is dosen't work see enterr image  https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgwEr.png